# Duplicate Items in cart

Tags: cart

Im new to this whole Magento stuff and was wondering, we have had a few issues of where a customer clicks a product twice and it buy two of the same product, is there a way of bringing a pop up saying you have two items in the cart the same?

Any suggestions would be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at base magento product view template after pressing add to cart the button is disabled `button.disabled = true;`

See /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

```
    var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
    productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
        if (this.validator.validate()) {
            var form = this.form;
            var oldUrl = form.action;

            if (url) {
               form.action = url;
            }
            var e = null;
            try {
                this.form.submit();
            } catch (e) {
            }
            this.form.action = oldUrl;
            if (e) {
                throw e;
            }

            if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                button.disabled = true;
            }
        }
    }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you instead thought about disabling the add to cart button after you click it so that the customer cannot actually press it twice?